# Informational complexity and effective methods of solution of convex extremal problems

Tags: reference-request, convex-optimization, mathematical-russian

I am looking for an electronic version of the following Russian paper:

- David Yudin and Arkadi Nemirovski. *Informational complexity and effective methods of solution of convex extremal problems*. Economics and mathematical methods, 12:357--369, 1976.

The journal goes by another name — *Ekonomika i matematicheskie metody*. Is there an English version or some paper with equivalent results? The theorem of interest is:

*Let $f$ be a submodular set-function defined on the subsets of $S$. Then the subset of $S$ minimizing $f$ can be found in polynomial time.*

The paper is referred to by another titled "Submodular functions and convexity" by Lovász.

Comment: You could try scholar.reddit.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the references of
http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~cswamy/courses/co759/approx-material/ellipsoid-survey.pdf

you find:
Iudin and Nemirovski
Translated in Matekon: Translations of Russian and East European Math. Economics 13, 25-45, Spring'77

Comment: Generally link only answers are discouraged. However, in this question, the OP is specifically asking a link. So this is OK.